# How to display emoji characters in PDF generated using xhtml2pdf in django?

Tags: django, xhtml2pdf

I'm trying to convert HTML to PDF using xhtml2pdf but not able to properly render the emoji characters in the HTML they appear as black boxes. I have tried with different fonts but still the same issue.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import time

import os
from io import BytesIO

from xhtml2pdf import pisa

source = """<html>
            <head>
              <title>Doc title</title>
              <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
              <meta charset="UTF-8">
            </head>
            <style>
                @media print {
                    @font-face {
                        font-family: Helvetica;
                        src: url("/absolute/path/to/Helvetica.ttf");
                    }
                }
                
            </style>
            <body>
                <p></p>
            </body>
        </html>"""


def convert_html_to_pdf(source):
    pdf = BytesIO()
    pisaStatus = pisa.CreatePDF(BytesIO(source), pdf, encoding='utf-8')
    return pdf


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pdf = convertHtmlToPdf(source)
    fd = open(os.path.join('/home/userX/', 'test-%s.pdf' % time.time()), "w+b")
    fd.write(pdf.getvalue())
    fd.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I was able to get emoji on PDF using Symbola font as following:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import time

import os
from io import BytesIO

from xhtml2pdf import pisa

source = """<html>
            <head>
              <title>Doc title</title>
              <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
              <meta charset="UTF-8">
            </head>
            <style>
                @media print {
                    @font-face {
                        font-family: Symbola;
                        src: url("/absolute/path/to/Symbola.ttf");
                    }
                }

                body {font-family: Symbola, sans-serif !important}
            </style>
            <body>
                <p></p>
            </body>
        </html>"""


def convert_html_to_pdf(source):
    pdf = BytesIO()
    pisaStatus = pisa.CreatePDF(BytesIO(source), pdf, encoding='utf-8')
    return pdf


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pdf = convertHtmlToPdf(source)
    fd = open(os.path.join('/home/userX/', 'test-%s.pdf' % time.time()), "w+b")
    fd.write(pdf.getvalue())
    fd.close()
```